# Standard C++ code for serialization/deserialization purposes

Tags: c++, serialization, buffer, allocator

I've been working with hardware APIs for a long time and almost all of the APIs that I've been working had a C interface. So, in many times I was working with naked `new`s, unsecure buffering and many C functions wrapped with C++ code. In the end, the frontier between C pure code and C++ pure code was messed up in my mind (and I don't know if clarify this frontier is useful at all).

Now, due a some new coding style requirements, I need to refactor all the code suspected to be insecure into more secure one written in C++ (assuming that the C++ code would be more secure) the final goal is to increase the code security using the tools that C++ brings on.

So, in order to get rid of all my confusion, I'm asking for help about a couple of topics of C/C++.

#### `memcpy` vs `std::copy`

AFAIK `memcpy` is a function that lies on the C libraries, so it isn't C++ish; in the other hand `std::copy` is a function into the STL so it's pure C++.

- But, this is true? after all, the `std::copy` will call `std::memcpy` (into the `cstring` header) if the data is trivially copiable.
- Refactoring all the `memcpy` calls into `std::copy` calls would make the code more "pure C++"?.

To deal with the new code style requirements I've decided to go on with the `memcpy` refactor after all, there's some questions about the `memcpy` and `std::copy`:

`memcpy` is type insecure, because it works with raw void pointers that can manage any kind of pointer regardless of it's type but at the same time is very flexible, the `std::copy` lacks of this flexibility assuring the type safety. At the first sight, `memcpy` is the best choice to work with serialization and deserialization routines (that's my real case of use indeed), for example, to send some values through a custom serial port library:

```
void send(const std::string &value)
{
    const std::string::size_type Size(value.size());
    const std::string::size_type TotalSize(sizeof(Size) + value.size());
    unsigned char *Buffer = new unsigned char[TotalSize];
    unsigned char *Current = Buffer;

    memcpy(Current, &Size, sizeof(Size));
    Current += sizeof(Size);

    memcpy(Current, value.c_str(), Size);

    sendBuffer(Buffer, TotalSize);

    delete []Buffer;
}
```

The code above works fine, but looks horrible; we're getting rid of the `std::string` encapsulation accesing it's internal memory through the `std::string::c_str()` method, we need to take care of allocations and deallocations of dynamic memory, play with pointers and treat all values as unsigned chars (see the next part), the question is: there's a better way to do this?

My first attempts at trying to solve the above problems using `std::copy` doesn't satisfy me altogether:

```
void send(const std::string &value)
{
    const std::string::size_type Size(value.size());
    const std::string::size_type TotalSize(sizeof(Size) + value.size());

    std::vector<unsigned char> Buffer(TotalSize, 0);

    std::copy(&Size, &Size + 1, Buffer.begin());
    std::copy(value.begin(), value.end(), Buffer.begin() + sizeof(Size));

    sendBuffer(Buffer.data(), TotalSize);
}
```

With the above approach, the memory management isn't a problem anymore, the `std::vector` takes the responsability of allocating, store and finally deallocate the data at the end of the scope, but the calls mixing `std::copy` with pointer arithmetics and iterators arithmetics is pretty annoying and in the end, I'm ignoring the `std::vector` encapsulation in the `sendBuffer` call after all.

After the previous tries, I've coded something with `std::stringstream`s but the results were even worse and now, I'm wondering if:

- There's a way to serialize objects and values in a safe way, without breaking encapsulations, without excesive or confusing pointer/iterator arithmetics and without dynamic memory management or it's just an impossible goal? (yes, I've heard about `boost::serialization`, but for now I'm not allowed to integrate it).

And:

- What's the best use of `std::copy` for serialization/deserialization purposes? (if any).
- The `std::copy` rationale is limited for copying containers or arrays and using it for raw memory is a bad choice?

#### `alloc`/`free` vs `new`/`delete` vs `std::allocator`

The other big topic is the allocation of memory. AFAIK the `malloc`/`free` functions aren't forbidden into the C++ scope although they're from C. And the `new`/`delete` operators are from the C++ scope and they aren't ANSI C.

- I'm right?
- `new`/`delete` can be used in ANSI C?

Assuming that I need to refactor all C-flavoured code into C++ code, I'm getting rid of all the `alloc`/`free` spreaded arround some legacy code and I've found that reserving dynamic memory is quite confusing, the void type doesn't carry any information about size, because of that it's impossible to reserve a data buffer using void as type:

```
void *Buffer = new void[100]; // <-- How many bytes is each 'void'?
```

Due the lack of pure-raw-binary-data-pointers, is a common practice to create pointers to `unsigned char`. The `char` in order to equal the elements count and size. And the `unsigned` in order to avoid unexpected signed-unsigned conversions during the data copy. Maybe it's a common practice, but it's a mess... `unsigned char` isn't `int` nor `float` nor `my_awesome_serialization_struct` if I'm forced to choose some kind of dummy pointer to binary data I will prefer `void *` instead of `unsigned char *`.

So when I need a dynamic buffer for serialization/deserialization purposes there's no way I can avoid the `unsigned char *` stuff in order to refactor into a type secure buffer management; but when I was rage-refactoring all the `alloc`/`free` pairs into `new`/`delete` pairs I read about the `std::allocator`.

The `std::allocator` allows to reserve memory chunks in a type-safe way, at the first sight I bet that it will be useful, but there's no great differences between allocating with `std::allocator<int>::allocate` or `new int` or so I thought, same was for `std::allocator<int>::deallocate` and `delete int`.

And now, I've lost the north about the dynamic memory management, that's why I'm asking:

- There's a good C++ practice involving the dynamic memory management for serialization/deserialization purposes that grants type-safe management?
- Is possible to avoid the use of `const char *` for serialization/deserialization memory Buffers?
- What's the rationale of `std::allocator` and what's its's use on serialization/deserialization scope? (if any).

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Didn’t read the entire question, but always use `std::copy` and never use `memcpy` in C++. It is safer and at least equally fast.

Comment: Not copying at all is even better.

Comment: Maybe you should look at google "protocol buffers" for a serialization library. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial

Answer (score 2):

My experience is, that type safety in C++ means not only that the compiler complains on type mismatches. It rather means you should in general not have to take care about the memory layout of your data. In fact, the C++ standard has only very few requirements on the memory layout of certain data types.

Your serialization is based on direct memory access, so, I'm afraid there won't be a simple "pure" C++ solution and particularly no general compiler/platform independent solution.

Comment: This answers almost all of my questions, but not all of them :(